# Rails 4 - Stripe webhook 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

```
 #stripe_controller.rb

 class StripeController < ApplicationController
   protect_from_forgery except: :stripe_webook  
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token    

   def stripe_webook
      data_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
      event_id = data_json['id']
      data = Stripe::Event.retrieve(event_id)
      handle_webhook(data)
      head :ok
   end
```

Only getting a 500 error when testing webhooks via Stripe dashboard, however using `curl`

```
curl -i     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
            -X POST -'{"id":"evt_0000000000000001","object":"event","api_version":"2016-03-07","created":1475273919,"data":{"object":{"id":"in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","object":"invoice","amount_due":2900,"application_fee":null,"attempt_count":1,"attempted":true,"charge":"ch_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx","closed":false,"currency":"usd","customer":"cus_xxxxxxxxxxxx","date":1475270308,"description":null,"discount":null,"ending_balance":0,"forgiven":false,"lines":{"object":"list","data":[{"id":"sub_xxxxxxxxxxx","object":"line_item","amount":2900,"currency":"usd","description":null,"discountable":true,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"period":{"start":1475270272,"end":1477862272},"plan":{"id":"tier_a_plan","object":"plan","amount":2900,"created":1475099850,"currency":"usd","interval":"month","interval_count":1,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"name":"Startup","statement_descriptor":null,"trial_period_days":15},"proration":false,"quantity":1,"subscription":null,"type":"subscription"}],"has_more":false,"total_count":1,"url":"/v1/invoices/in_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/lines"},"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"next_payment_attempt":1475360318,"paid":false,"period_end":1475270272,"period_start":1475269805,"receipt_number":null,"starting_balance":0,"statement_descriptor":null,"subscription":"sub_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","subtotal":2900,"tax":null,"tax_percent":null,"total":2900,"webhooks_delivered_at":1475270308}},"livemode":false,"pending_webhooks":1,"request":null,"type":"invoice.payment_failed"}'     https://myurl.com/stripe/webhook
```

I am getting `200`

After searching for answers - I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

That 500 is coming from your code somewhere, and only you can figure out where.  Either step through it in a debugger, or throw in some log statements to see how far you get before it explodes.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to fetch an `Event` that doesn't exist (because it's a test webhook with id `evt_0000000001` or something)

Comment out this line and it should work: `data = Stripe::Event.retrieve(event_id)`

Stripe should make this test event retrievable for better testing.

Also, best practice is to have `head: ok` at the top